# Yahoo weather API weather icon image

Tags: php, weather, yahoo-api, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

So im using the yahoo weather API for a website im working on. Right now it is calling default images for the weather icons, which do not look very nice at all. I wanted to use the newer images which they us on their website [here](http://weather.yahoo.com/).

Here is the code im using that I believe are calling the default image sets:

`$weather_contents = $weather->channel->item->description;
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$weather_contents, $img);
$weather_img = $img[0][0];`

And [here](http://malikai.com/test/) is a link to what im working on. You will notice the difference between the quality of the weather icons I have and what they currently use on yahoo.

I am pretty much a newbie when working with this weather stuff, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Cheers

Comment: maybe they dont want you stealing their graphics

Comment: Could be, although im using their graphics for the images that are calling now.

Answer (score 0):

You should try definitely metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/weather-api/).
Here is a working example with awesome icons. (You can change it of course)

http://jsbin.com/isukam/1

Disclosure: I own this awesome API.
Let me know if you need help.